# d= [int(4) for i in range(5)]

Tags: python, syntax

I am having trouble understanding why following works in Python. I would have never thought of creating list this way and yet I found method of composition using this construct. Why is this construct syntactically correct and how does the compiler resolve this statement?

```
>>> d= [int(4) for i in range(5)]
>>> d
[4, 4, 4, 4, 4]
```

Comment: `int(4)` is simply 4.

Comment: Martijn, the duplicate you linked to was also marked as a duplicate, by yourself :-)

Answer (score 1):

It's called *list comprehension* and, in this case, simply creates a list of elements, all with the integer value 4, for each of the items in the `for` section (the values 0 through 4 inclusive).

But `int(4)` is not really required, you can use `4` instead. However, even *that's* overkill for this particular situation, I'd prefer the more succinct:

```
[4] * 5
```

myself, leaving the `for`-loop form for more complicated stuff such as getting the cubes of odd numbers whose squares are less that a given value:

```
>>> [i**3 for i in range(99) if i*i < 99 and i%2 == 1]
[1, 27, 125, 343, 729]
```

Yes, a rather contrived example, but it shows how you can use list comprehensions to do some truly powerful stuff.